# Context Free Grammar $L = \{a^i(b+c)^jd^k | i<j+k; i,j,k>0\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I'm trying to design a CFG that accept the words of the following language:

$$L = \{a^i(b+c)^jd^k  \mid  i<j+k; \quad  i,j,k>0\}$$

My first approximation would be to do $i = j+k$ as something like:

$S\to aSd \mid X$

$X\to aXY \mid aY $

$Y\to b \mid c$

But then I don't know how to make the jump to the $<$.

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: I always have problems with the axiom. Which should be the first transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see a condition $i<j+k$, you can translate that to the condition $i+\ell=j+k$ where $\ell>0$, then use the methods you know for handling $=$ instead of $<$.

See our [reference question on this subject](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755) for more systematic answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure that make sense , but i don't really understand how to apply it to my problem.

Comment: @Xhark, then I suggest you study the material in our reference question.  That's why I linked it.  I'm happy to help you understand concepts and learn new approaches to solve problems, but solving exercise-style problems for you wouldn't really help anyone.